# How to parse model data to listview widget

Tags: flutter

Having challenges parsing this item model data to listview widget , any recommendation ? l have got stuck now .

```
class Item  implements ListItem {
  String name;
  Image image;
  BaseFare baseFare;
  List<Pricing> pricing;
  int id;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;


  Item({
    this.name,
    this.image,
    this.baseFare,
    this.pricing,
    this.id,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Item(
    name: json["name"],
    image: Image.fromJson(json["image"]),
    baseFare: BaseFare.fromJson(json["base_fare"]),
    createdAt: json["created_at"],
    updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on this example from Flutter Docs:

```
// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');

  return parsePhotos(response.body);
}
```

You can do the same at parsePhotos method and return a list of any widget you want.